# CodeIgniter reusable message library

Tags: codeigniter, message, config

I'm using Message library (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Message/) to display error messages on my site. This is the code that I'm using to display a message:

```
$this->message->set('error',$this->config->item('error.login'));
```

Right now I'm storing common messages in my config file (config/config.php) instead of writing the message every time. Is there a better way to do it? The config file is getting very long.

What I'm looking for is a better way to store re-usable text strings.

Comment: Consider using XML files. This way you'll be able to localize your application quickly by creating language-specific XMLs. I have little experience with XML in PHP, so can't provide any high-quality example.  The good point to start is [PHP's DOM package](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: JOHN - CI has a language class which makes multi-language sites easy - no XML required. [link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's language class is what you're looking for:
[CI Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

```
$this->message->set('error',$this->lang->line('error.login'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A config file is more or less how you'd want to do it. It is simple, clear and light. But just because you are keeping it in *a* config file, that does not mean you need to keep it in config.php. The Config class allows you to have multiple config files, so have a special one for messages. Heck, you could even have several special ones for languages, and leave the one you are looking for in the config.php file!

```
 $this->config->load( $this->config->get( "language_file_name" ) );
```