# How to show 'success' message on form submit without changing URL?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I have a PHP site (with CodeIgniter) that includes a registration form. I have a page with some details, which links to the form on a separate page. The form posts to a third URL which does the processing and redirects back to the first page if it's successful (or the form page if not).

Currently I am adding a parameter for success: `example.com/page?success=1` which shows a success message. The problem is that some people have been sharing this URL (and clicking the Facebook Like button) so when another user opens that URL they see a message "thanks for registering!" which they obviously haven't done yet.

I thought this was the standard way of doing forms (submitting to one URL and redirecting to another) but is there a better way? I don't want to post back to the same page because then you get the POSTDATA warning when trying to reload the page.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120746/codeigniter-reusable-message-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would set your flag for success in the session to display this message when the next page loads. This is commonly referred to as a Flash Message. You would then check the value/existence of this session flag and show your message or not accordingly. In most frameworks there is built in functionality for this which includes the clean up of the flag on the next request so that the message is only displayed directly after the action generating it is taken.

From the CI [Sessions Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for
>   informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").
>
> Note: Flash variables are prefaced with "flash_" so avoid this prefix
>   in your own session names.
>
> To add flashdata:
>
> ```
> $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
> ```
>
> You can also pass an array to set_flashdata(), in the same manner as
>   set_userdata().
>
> To read a flashdata variable:
>
> ```
> $this->session->flashdata('item');
> ```
>
> If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an
>   additional request, you can do so using the keep_flashdata() function.
>
> ```
> $this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You have three ways to do this

- The way you're using
- Not actually redirecting but sending request(s) with AJAX
- SESSION (or, in edge case, cookies)

If you select to use SESSION, you can just assign a session variable to true

```
$_SESSION['registered'] = true;
```

and checking it on the first page

```
if (isset($_SESSION['registered'])) { 
      unset($_SESSION['registered']); 
      // shot the message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some verification checks in your code that handles the processing of the form data to make sure that the required fields are filled out.  Otherwise, you should be redirecting to your first page to have the user fill out the form.

Also, this could be handled via AJAX, but that would be a second step to having the proper verification in your form-processing page

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <form method="post">
     <input type="text">
     <input name="submitted" type="submit">
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST['submitted']{
    //post was submitted process it

    if(/*whatever you're doing to the form succeeds*/){
        //show success
    }
}
```

POST will not show variables in the URL.

Comment: I'd like to know the same so I can learn - I suspect it's some Codeigniter quirk from reading the above answers.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski because it doesn't remotely answer the question. The problem is not about how to read postdata.

Comment: The question appeared to be about how to submit a form without $_GET variables cludging up the URL. Switching to GET is a valid solution, and probably the easiest.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski I also said in the question, "I don't want to post back to the same page because then you get the POSTDATA warning when trying to reload the page."

Answer (score -1):

Several solutions here, one would be to check for the form submission and if it hasn't been submitted redirect to the page with the form on it.

ie:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    // process the form
    }
else
    {
    //redirect to the form itself
    header( 'Location: http://www.yourform.com' ) ;
    }
?>
```